# iOS: Core Motion used to detect larger movements over distance?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, core-motion

I have a GPS app that I would like to detect if the user is standing still and not moving.  Using Core Location works for this, but is sometimes not accurate because new updates move and gives the illusion of speed and motion.

So, I am wondering if in addition to that, I can also use Core Motion.  Is this a good idea to detect motion such as someone walking, running, driving, etc, and know when they are no longer doing that motion?  Or, is Core Motion only for small movements such as tilting the device or lifting it to your ear?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to tell others who visit this question what I've learned and what I think about this approach.

I have been doing some research of my own to know whether this is possible, and more importantly, even if it is what is the battery consumption and accuracy of the location change detected. For Android though, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation/7835988#7835988) was asked quite sometime back. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation/7835988#7835988) provides links to [this  Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k). At 23:20, the speaker talks about how difficult it is to achieve this and the accuracy you will achieve in the results.

Even though I have to come to realize the battery consumption from sensors on the iPhone is a little lesser than in most Android phones, I still think this is a costly affair in terms of accuracy and battery consumption.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the GPS with the sensor readings to distinguish between walking, running, etc. if you combine the tilt angle frequency change and the GPS speed information (you need to do some  work to get some of this info of course, but thats the way to do it).

Comment: Yes, I already have all the GPS information. But I was wanting to combine this with data from core motion. My question is if Core Motion is capable of sensing forward motion?  But with some sort of threshold so it isn't just sensing the user removing the device from their backpack.

Comment: like i mentioned, you will need to use the heading information to sense which direction the user is heading and the tilt angle frequency change over time to see what kind of activity the user is making.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about 4 different measurements from 4 different sensors (technically more than 4 but..) -

1. Latitude & Longitude - from CoreLocation. It uses a mix of GPS + cell tower triangulation.
2. Accelerometer - the current orientation of the device in 3D space.
3. Gyroscope - orientation of the device on its own axis.
4. Magnetometer - which tells you which direction a device is point w.r.t south,north,east,west

Of all these I think only Latitude & Longitude are of use to you. Basically what you do is to make the sensitivity (i.e. the update rate from the sensor) a bit more relaxed. With some tweaking around with this you should be able to tell with good accuracy if a person is standing or moving.

Comment: yes, so that as you say just by removing the device from your bag should not tell u that you are moving.

Comment: While this sounds like a great idea, I have done a great amount of filtering already and, at this point I am unsure how to filter it in the way you mention.

Comment: sorry, not, not sure how I clicked it as the answer. I personally don't want to have to use yet another sensor (accelerometer) if I don't have to, because I worry about battery. I just wanted to be able to find an algorithm that works to filter out the "gitter" of GPS when standing still.  So far, I just have suggestions, with no code help.  I have tried all I can think of, but nothing has worked so far.