# Calculating user moving speed in android

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

I need to calculate *Speed with which the user is moving*. So we need two things to calculate speed which are `GPS` and `Accelerometer`.

But both have their limitations.

1)`GPS` is not available all the time.While I getting the current location of user always I am              getting from `Network provider` only and not from `GPS`.

2)`Accelerometer` is not accurate.

So which approach should I go with?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An implementation, based on the GPS, is available [at this link](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SpeedDemo)

Comment: The link is dead now. It is always recommended to add the content on SO and provide a reference link of the original post for more details.

Answer (score 9):

The most accurate results can be obtained by using **both of them**, through **sensor fusion.** See my previous answer to question [Using accelerometer to calculate speeds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10921395/341970) or to another question [GPS V.S. accelerometer to calculate distance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9916926/341970).

As for the accuracy of the accelerometer, see [Get velocity from 3DVector using accelerometer sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9957625/341970).

If you want to track the user indoor, see what you can actually do at question [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970).

Comment: @Ali - any example for this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can call .getSpeed() on the locationprovider