# Best method to get the rough user movement speed

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

I am using Google-Play-Services to track user activities. In case of a walking activity or bicycle activity I want to calculate the rough speed the user is moving. Is there any simple method? Location updates by Google-Play-Services are sometimes quite inaccurate since there is no good GPS signal in particular areas.

By the way, I realised the GPS location is getting very accurate when I start the google maps navigation application. I wonder how to get a location with the same percision without starting Google Navigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating user moving speed in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643727/calculating-user-moving-speed-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If the Location was created by GPS, then use `location.getSpeed().`