# Get Geo Speedometer -- Android

Tags: android, performance

I am new to speedometer concept. I am writing app to get the speed,latitude,longitude using google map and GEO. At present i can able to get how much speed from my travel using google map2. Is that any API Call to show the Geo Speedometer same like speed calculation. Please give me suggestion on this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to calculate the user's speed? IF so I'd recommend reading this post: [Calculating user moving speed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643727/calculating-user-moving-speed-in-android)

Comment: Thanks.. Actually i can able to get the speed using geo tracker and i can get text the values. But i want to show that in Speedometer, is any api to show the speedometer.

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, what exactly is geotracker?