# Figure out Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location-services

I am trying to develop an android application that can do task according to the lat/long. This is something like if I am in particular suburb (Lets say I am in Belconnen, ACT Australia, I would like to get the details of that place automatically) - if I move out the border of belconnen then I have to show some other details.

If you check this google maps link: http://goo.gl/4mItcF you would see the red border is only belconnen suburb.

My question is how do I give the borders in my App (meaning how do I tell my App that I am now in belconnen, ACT? Is it by getting lat/long along the borders store them in DB and check if I am inside required lat/long, if that is the case DB would have huge numbers only for Belconnen, ACT right?

Or is there an easier way to get the borders?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: please refer this link :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm

Comment: Did you check GeoFencing?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ I did I believe this requires internet. I am looking for solution that work offline rather than through internet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way , it is called Reverse Geocoding. You can use it by two ways :

**1. Using `Geocoder` class of Android -**

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Here you use `lat = -35.2374551` and `lng = 149.0672515` for Belconnen, ACT Australia. Check out the function [getFromLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) for more information.

**2. Using Google REST Web Services :**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-35.2374551,149.0672515   (JSON)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=-35.2374551,149.0672515    (XML)

pass comma separated latitude and longitude and u will get the most precise location for that in response. Find more information here [Reverse Geocoding google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

As soon as you go out of Belconnen, ACT Australia, the address in response will no longer contain this and you can put some logic to get your desired behavior.

Comment: Your 2 point requires internet. I am looking for solution that can work even if internet is not working.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, you would like to create a Location Aware Application.

As per the Android documentation, Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app.

**Step 1 - Knowing the current Location of the User**

Google recommends to use FusionProvider API for this purpose. It is one of the location APIs in Google Play services where you can specify requirements at a high level, like high accuracy or low power. It also optimizes the device's use of battery power.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html

**Step 2** - Based on the latitude and Longitude information retrieved in the location object, you can use the below **Google web service to get the postal code of the location**.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=lattitude,longitude&sensor=true

**Step 3 - How Frequent can we retrieve the location information**

Turning on the listeners continuously will impact the device battery highly. So, to avoid this, we need to minimize the frequency of retrieving the location information.

I would recommend to measure the distance traveled by the user and based on that set the next location update trigger. Since you are concerned about boundary only, we can set a high value based on the device acceleration. 
 Refer the below links for more details on how to implement this effectively.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644809/623517

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't check the location always. This is done only when user opens my APP. I have few important details stored in local DB. All I need is when I open the APP according to location I want to put the details and show it. For which I need to know the location and it borders? GEO FENCING works it good for small places but how can I give it big places?

Answer (score 0):

You can get full address from lat long and then search your city or location. This answer explain how to do it : [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

If you want further flexibility you can use geofence : http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Address format is perfect idea which has already been implemeneted but what if i don't have internet i would like show limited data.

Comment: For Geofencing: I have feed the lat and long to compare my current lat/long for which I will have huge sets of lat/long only for the belconnen, Australia right?

Comment: In geofencing you basically provide a circle and rest is handled by android, You don't have to compare yourself. For offline stuff you have to give try as i don.t know.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the region with LatLngBounds (com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds).
Use it like this:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new Builder();
for (int i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    builder.include(points[i]);
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

And then check if your location falls inside it:

```
if (bounds.contains(myLatLng)) {
    //your implementation
}
```

I know this approach cannot give perfect results but it seems to be more efficient then using the geofences.

Answer (score 0):

```
        LocationManager lm;
        lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria c=new Criteria();
        String provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
        Location l=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        double latitude = l.getLatitude(); // latitude
        double longitude = l.getLongitude(); // longitude
```