# How to find device position change using accelerometer?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, accelerometer

I am designing a Windows Phone 7 project where I need to determine position changes of the device. I tried to use accelerometer, but it gives info on current orientation of my phone and I don't know how to convert this data to position delta. Here is some example code:

```
void acc_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
{
    AccelerometerReading newdata = e.SensorReading;
    Vector3 vect = newdata.Acceleration - data.Acceleration;
    //what comes here???
}
```

The method above is called when accelerometer data is changed. But I don't know how to convert this data to position change of a device (i.e. I move my phone in X direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970)

You get position by integrating the linear acceleration twice but **the error is horrible. It is useless in practice.**

See the above linked answer to get some ideas what you actually can do.

Comment: The linked answer gives you some tips. Good luck anyhow!