# butterworth low-pass filter for android

Tags: java, android, filtering, accelerometer

I'm currently involved in attempting to make a crude pedometer. 
It has come to the stage where i am reading in signals and plotting them on Excel to analyse...
The data is quite noisy due to step bounce back and various other reasons. I am taking in a single acceleration vector and was trying to use the following DSP filter design tool that i found through the york cs department to design a Butterworth low-pass filter:

http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html

It may be that I am inputting the wrong values for the necessary fields but at the same time I am having trouble translating the Ansi "C" code to Java!

Would anyone be able to lend a helping hand?

Comment: I am not sure that translating C to Java blindly, without understanding it, is the right approach. Anyhow, for pedestrian localization, see [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970). In particular, the "Enhancing the Performance of Pedometers Using a Single Accelerometer" gives a simple pedometer algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I have actually implemented a very basic version for the movement detection based on: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.htm

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) { // check sensor type
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];

    float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z) / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    _SR.setText("accelationSquareRoot" + String.valueOf(accelationSquareRoot)); // display 3D acceleration vector
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= progressDouble) {
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 15) { 
            return;
        }
        lastUpdate = actualTime;
        ++count;
    } 
}
```

The filter was more to show some analysis of how the accelerometer works and to find out if i could make it more accurate.