# Detect device moving distance

Tags: android, location

What is the best way to detect user device moving? For now I'm using network/GPS location determining best coordinates on small interval. But it would be great to improve accuracy user movement information up to meters. Geolocation strongly depends on network connection quality or weather.. Is there a way to find very accurate info about device moving? May be accelerometer can help?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)

Answer (score 3):

Accelerometers tend to be a poor way to measure distance moved, as the slightest error in the measurement of acceleration or orientation rapidly integrates to a substantial position error.  That's even more true with low-accuracy components used in a consumer device - inertial navigation systems used in aircraft/spacecraft are not cheap, and even those might not be accurate enough for your needs.

If you want positioning accuracy, especially over any duration of time, you need to measure in relation to the outside world, as GPS does.  There are various beacon systems available using things like ultrasonics, or even adding pretend satellites to the GPS system which you could look into, but it's not going to be simple.

Comment: thanks for full answer. is it possible to determine at least fact of moving with accelerometer?