# How to obtain only linear acceleration from accelerometer using gyroscope?

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

I have a small remote controlled car going on the room floor. For simplicity let us assume it is moving along say x-axis. Now, the floor seems flat but there are very minute uneven bumps in every surface. So whenever the car is not exactly flat (as it was at starting position) or in other words whenever the car has even slightest of tilt then,
Total Acceleration obtained from accelerometer = Linear Acceleration + Acceleration due to tilt

My question is how to remove the acceleration due to tilt so that I get only linear acceleration? Can I somehow use gyroscope to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented sensor fusion for the [Shimmer platform](http://www.shimmer-research.com/products-2/shimmer-revisions) based on this manuscript, it's basically a tutorial:

[Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA)

This manuscript pretty much answers your question.

These have also been a big help:

[An introduction to inertial navigation](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk//techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-696.pdf)

[An Introduction to the Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf)

[Pedestrian Localisation for Indoor Environments](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/www/files/publications/public/abr28/ojw28_thesis.pdf)

[Combine Gyroscope and Accelerometer Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590385/341970)

**Just promise me you won't try double integrating the linear acceleration** because [it won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970) and I suspect that it is [what you are trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11087076/341970)

Comment: Hi.The last link you posted is my question itself and double integration is exactly what I am planning to do. I know you have already mentioned that this wont work. But this is my project and I have to try. Right now my accuracy is this: if I move the sensor say 40 cm along a straight line and just use accelerometer data (assuming that I just get Linear Acceleration), I get random vlaues for position if I repeat the test. Example: test 1 : Pos= 51cm , test 2 : Pos= 46cm , test 3 : Pos = 76cm, test 4 : Pos= 19cm, test 5:Pos= 109cm. Can I get more closer or atleast constant error using gyro?