# iOS sliding distance with accelerometer

Tags: ios, accelerometer, distance, physics-engine

I'm trying to measure the distance a device slides using the accelerometer. This is how I'm doing it:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    CGFloat interval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - lastTime;

    CGFloat velocity = ((acceleration.y + lastAcceleration) / 2) * interval * 9.8 + lastVelocity;

    totalDistance += velocity * interval;

    lastAcceleration = acceleration.y;
    lastVelocity = velocity;

    lastTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}
```

The results are extremely erratic, ranging +/- 30% of the actual value. Are my calculations correct, and if so, how can I make this code more accurate?

Comment: Have you considered that friction along a surface will cause vibrations to change the sensor values as it moves while moving it in the air is a much more smooth transition?

What you're trying to do is one of the hardest problems in motion sensing and without a way to re-orient the estimated distance traveled over time will get worse and worse.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do the [infamous double-integral](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7835988/341970). I am surprised you only have 30% error.

Comment: Hmmm... so what you're saying is that this isn't possible with the iPhone's current hardware?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of some of the inaccuracies of the hardware by applying a filter on the results.

here is a library to do a fast fourier transform on the values.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/