# Kalman filter with acceleration. State or Control vector?

Tags: filter, bayesian, kalman-filter, acceleration

I have a basic understanding question in Kalman filter which I haven't found an answer yet.

Assume I want to implement a Kalman filter with a constant acceleration dynamic.

I can either add the acceleration the state vector and F matrix - Xt = X(t-1) +V*t+0.5a*t^2

OR, I can add the acceleration to the U control vector.

What is the profind difference between these two methods and given I have accel measurements, what is the best policy?

You can find these two approaches in google.

All the best,

Roi

Answer (score 1):

U refers to input to the system in standard control theory state space representation (for more information see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation)) and therefore what you do depends on the context of your specific problem.

It sounds like you are trying to estimate position of a target moving with constant acceleration. This means that the target's position has a defined model of motion. This model of motion will be encoded in F. Think of a bicyclist looking at the speedometer while rolling down a hill and not pedaling at all (bicyclist has no input to the system). If the acceleration is not constant (the hill has a varying slope) and you have access to real time measurements of the acceleration then you can modify your system to estimate acceleration as well. If the acceleration is unknown then read the following stackoverflow post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15096989/3000187).

If you were tracking the target while having direct control of the acceleration then you would put it in U. Think of YOU being the bicyclist looking at the speedometer (estimating the speed) and deciding whether you should pedal faster or slower.

Comment: If one have (absolute) direct control of the acceleration then it does not need to consider dynamic model matrix (F=identity matrix), right? in another words, in which situations we don't need to consider dynamic model matrix? Is it correct: whenever there is no dynamic model for the problem, then we should considere identity matrix or F?