# Calculation User speed and distance using device accelerometer android

Tags: android, performance, accelerometer

Hi I am developing small android application in which i wanted to calculate user speed and distance covered by user using device accelerometer. So what I did I take samples of acceleration in time frame like 1 min. From accelerometer i got x y and z coordinates. I took x coordinate values and take average of it. and from that i am calculating speed of user.

But it not giving proper value. 
Is there any way to do this? How to do this so that it will give me good approx value?
I did this in following way:

```
// sum of no samples of acceleration points 
sum_acc = sum_acc+event.values[0];
// avg of acc
avg_acc = sum_acc/no_of_samples;
// speed of user 
speed = avg_acc*time_frame;
// distance
distance = speed*time;
```

I need better and accurate result. Need Help. thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You say speed and distance,

For the **Speed**, instead of using the accelerometer, make Location requests within a given time interval, get two locations, within that time interval and convert it to miles, then divide the location by the time interval. From there, you have your speed.
To make location requests and get updates, follow this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html),

For the **distance**, use the Geolocator api and make requests for the device's current position after a given time interval, sum the distances covered and you get your total distance.