# zero Velocity detection Using accelerometer data

Tags: accelerometer

I am using an Accelerometer to track the linear motion of an object x-axis. I need to precisely find the time instant when the object stops, so that i can integrate the accelerometer data to track the path of the motion from the start to the completion of motion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)

Comment: I don't know what you would like to do exactly but you cannot calculate the path of the motion based on the accelerometer readings. See the question linked above.

Comment: Actually i need ti distinguish between constant acceleration and zero velocity states, in which cases accelerometer returns 0 value. There might be some errors due to gravity and rotations. I have a calibration function to correct those errors. But only problem i do not know how to determine the motion stop.