# Motion Tracking using Sensor fusion

Tags: algorithm, accelerometer, motion-detection

Currently I am using an accelerometer, Gyro and magnetometer for motion tracking application.I have a 9D sensor fusion functionality to calculate the orientations and gravity cancellation from accelerometer data. How do i now calculate the position of the object in three dimensions? Kindly suggest any algorithm which could give good accuracy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)

Comment: The bad news is that you cannot do that in general, the current MEMS sensors are not accurate enough. The answer to that question gives alternatives, what you could do instead.

Answer (score 2):

Extended Kalman filter can give you the best results for motion tracking if you are working on real time application. I would suggest you to refer a book Multi Sensor Data fusion with MATLAB (CRC Press).