# Circular Motion Tracking in 3D

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope, motion-detection

How can i track a circular motion in 3D? Currently I'm using accelerometer & gyroscope and sensor fusion algorithm to calculate orientation. But i cannot calculate the position accurately and hence unable to track the motion precisely.Please suggest any algorithm or an alternate method.

Comment: Are you integrating twice for position?  That's dodgy.

Comment: Yes.I'm Using double integration.What could be better alternative?

Comment: Is it true repeated circular motion in 3D?  You just don't know the precise location on the path?

Comment: It is a repeated circular motion at varying speed.

Comment: You need to do something that plays on the repeating the same track.  Maybe something with just velocity?  If you have velocity, then you also have position (without integrating) because you already know the track.

Comment: True. But i want to extend it to non-circular motions (May be some random motions in 3D).

Comment: This is beyond me.  What does the gyroscope give you?  Are you using it to enhance the accelrometer?

Comment: I get angular velocity from Gyro. Yes I use gyro to correct accelerometer data.

Comment: I don't know.  Could the gyro have lag?  How do you ensure the best sensor fusion?

Comment: @Jaipal *"i want to extend it to non-circular motions (May be some random motions in 3D)"* The sad news is that you can't; these MEMS sensors are not accurate enough, see for example [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7829097/341970) and also for what you could do instead. As for circular motions, in your problem, doesn't the orientation in itself determine the position on the circular path? If yes, just use orientation and it will work beautifully.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I will try using orientation.