# Applying Quaternion based correction on accelerometer data/displacement data?

Tags: accelerometer, quaternions, gyroscope

I am using an IMU sensor providing raw accelerometer, gyroscope and quaternion data.

After the pre processing I am trying to use the sensor data for accurate motion tracking. However the tracking on a single floor results in a tilt in the z-direction. I tried to correct the accelerometer data using the quaternion based rotation matrix and then integrating  it taking care of the zero velocity windows.

Still I am getting the tilt in the z-direction. Is there a way of further correcting the acclereometer data or the integrated displacement data using the quaternions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation)

Comment: Also The rate gyroscope data on integration gives three angles which are Yaw, Pitch and Roll.

Is it true that the angles obtained by integrating the gyroscope signal are NOT Euler angles and are the Tait Bryan angles. If not what are the angles i.e. angular position obtained after integrating the gyroscope data signify.

Is there any way of converting between the pitch roll and yaw angles and the Euler angles?

Comment: There are different conventions to define the Euler angles. One convention leads to yaw, pitch and roll.

Comment: Could you please kindly point me to those conventions of converting Euler angles to yaw, pitch and roll and  vice versa

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles although it is only helpful if you know both the source and the target convention.