# How to calculate the displacement distance of the mobile device using android accelerometer sensor?

Tags: android, accelerometer

Hi can anyone give sample code to find the traveled distance using android accelerometer sensor.can anybody explain that  where to call

double Accel2mms(double accel, double freq)

this method..from the following link 
[How to find distance of displacement using accelerometer sensor in android smartphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092570/how-to-find-distance-of-displacement-using-accelerometer-sensor-in-android-smart)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092570/how-to-find-distance-of-displacement-using-accelerometer-sensor-in-android-smart)

Comment: Yes.but i can get where to call double Accel2mms(double accel, double freq){
    double result = 0;
    result = (gravity*accel)/(2*PI*freq);
    return result;
} this method ...and i don't know to calculate frequency value in that.can u help on this.