# Calculate Velocity from Accelerometer of Android Phone

Tags: android, position, accelerometer, velocity, robotics

[image: Mobile phoe Acceleration Velority and position of my mobile phone]

The results is wrong my phone is steady and the velocity is wrong.I can't calculate the velocity right so i can calculate the position after that

Comment: You don't show your calculation code. However it will help to read: [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7829097/295004)