# Does we have possibility to get current speed in android without GPS?

Tags: android, gps

Is there a way to do it without GPS?
And, in the best way, without network.

Thanks.

Comment: In theory, if you start from rest you could use the accelerometer to do this. In practice, probably not.

Comment: You may try to get Acceleration base on accelerometer, get the time, calculate the speed. But that's completely unreliable, even if phone was still.

Comment: @Marius If the phone is still it's easy ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton not so easy, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027724/what-is-the-real-world-accuracy-of-phone-accelerometers-when-used-for-positionin)

Comment: @Marius If the phone is still, which is pretty easy to detect even with its inaccurate accelerometer, the velocity is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accurate speed measurements require some form of distance/time calculation, unless you want to play some hairy games with the accelerometer and don't mind being completely wrong.

See e.g., http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity